# css overflow-y not working

Tags: css, overflow

So I have applied

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

to the body. Like so.

```
    body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', tahoma;
    background-color:#F4FFFF;
    height:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But the page will not scroll down. I have no idea why. [Here is the page.](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "`position: fixed`" in your "`#load`". Try to remove it and see.

Comment: ah i see. Thank you. Although now I need to have it so that it is position: fixed until the page has loaded.

Comment: Then after load.. you change it to default.

Comment: found the bit of javascript which does this. website is updated thanks